# Can't launch instances on new Devstack installation

Tags: virtualization, ubuntu-16.04, openstack, qemu

I just "successfully" installed Devstack on my Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS. I can connect to the Horizon Dashboard without problems but when i try to launch an instance i get errors.

If it try run a cirros image( QCOW2 format) or a Xenial(VMDK) without creating a volume i get the error:

```
Image %(image_id)s is unacceptable: not able to analyze 'qemu-img info'.
```

If i also make it create a volume, I get this one:

```
Volume %(volume_id)s did not finish being created even after we waited 0 seconds or 1 attempts. And its status is "error".
```

It doesn't look like it is a image's problem.